# Removing Stains from Laminate Flooring

Tags: staining, laminate-floor

These stains are from some colors from a Long time ago. Please help me to remove them. I tried many things like nail polish remover, clothes stain remover, etc with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Post your address, one of us will be right over... On a serious note, welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Also, read up on [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] to add some more details. What kind of "stain remover"? What kind of finish is currently on the floor? Is it real hardwood or is it some sort of modern, laminated veneer flooring?

Comment: If "nail polish" was actually "nail polish remover" then you may have fixed that color there.